# Sending data from javascript to php and converting

Tags: php, json, post

**TLDR version**

Simply just trying to convert `{"created":1517517725555,"steamId":"randomsetofnumbers"}` that I get as a POST variable to a class I made in PHP (see below)

**LONG version**

Forgive my ignorance, I'm not a PHP developer but I've been taken on a task to develop a PHP application at work. I seem to understand everything I need to understand to complete this. However, I seem to be stuck on one thing. I am sending data (specifically an object) from javascript to PHP stringified (as you always would), as such:

```
data: {action: 'initSqs', sqsObj: JSON.stringify(_sqsObj)},
```

`sqsObj` is the object in question.

On the PHP side, I can read this data via a simple `$_POST['sqsObj']` and I'm able to read the data. Example of actual data (I copied and pasted):

`{"created":1517517725555,"steamId":"randomsetofnumbers"}` (I've omitted the actual steamId, and just replaced with 'randomsetofnumbers').

So that's the `$_POST['sqsObj']` on the PHP side. Looks great! My only problem now is that I'm having the HARDEST time converting this **thing** (not really sure what it is, is it json? is it an object? json_decode returns blank, so I assume it can't be an `object` (in PHP at least, this is a valid object in JS)).

I've tried to verify this being an object by simply doing `json_decode($_POST['sqsObj'])` and it returns nothing. I've tried to access properties via `$_POST['sqsObj']->created` which doesn't work.

What I really want to do is convert this **thing** to a class I made in PHP:

```
  class SqsObj {
    public $steamId = '';
    public $created = '';
  }
```

So that I can simply access the properties when I need them. How can I do this??

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here's how I'm sending the data in JS

```
  console.log(_sqsObj);
  //in console this will show as: 
  //{created: "1517519186045", steamId: "randomsetofnumbers"}
  jQuery.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'sqsController.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {action: 'initSqs', sqsObj: JSON.stringify(_sqsObj)},
      //what is obj1 and obj2??
      success: function (data, success) {
        if(success == 'success' && data) {
          $('#initHunter').addClass('waiting').html('Searching for Bully Hunter');

        }
        // if( !('error' in obj) ) {
        //     yourVariable = obj.result;
        // }
        // else {
        //     console.log(obj.error);
        // }
      },
      error: function (obj1, obj2) {
      }
  });
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here's my PHP script that's handling this

```
<?php
  require 'vendor/autoload.php';
  use Aws\Sqs\SqsClient;
  use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

  //error_reporting(0);

  class SendMessageResponse {
    public $MD5OfMessageAttributes = '';
    public $MD5OfMessageBody = '';
    public $MessageId = '';
    public $SequenceNumber = '';
  }

  class SqsObj {
    public $steamId = '';
    public $created = '';
  }

  if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
      $action = $_POST['action'];
      switch($action) {
        case 'initSqs': {
          initSqs(); break;
        }
      }
  }

  function initSqs() {
    $ret = new SendMessageResponse();
    $sqsObj = new SqsObj();
    if(isset($_POST['sqsObj']) && !empty($_POST['sqsObj'])) {
      error_log($_POST['sqsObj']);
      $obj = json_decode($_POST['sqsObj']);
      error_log($obj);
    }
    // Pass the provider to the client.
    $client = new SqsClient([
        'profile'     => 'default',
        'region'      => 'us-east-1',
        'version'     => '2012-11-05'
    ]);

    $params = [
        'MessageGroupId'=> 1,
        'MessageDeduplicationId'=>1,
        'MessageAttributes' => [
            "SteamId" => [
                'DataType' => "String",
                'StringValue' => ""
            ],
            "DateCreated" => [
                'DataType' => "String",
                'StringValue' => ""
            ]
        ],
        'MessageBody' => "Victim {insert steam id} is looking for help",
        'QueueUrl' => '[omitted]'
    ];
    try {
        //$result = $client->sendMessage($params);
        //$ret->MD5OfMessageAttributes = $result['MD5OfMessageAttributes'];
        //$ret->MD5OfMessageBody = $result['MD5OfMessageBody'];
        //$ret->MessageId = $result['MessageId'];
        //$ret->SequenceNumber = $result['SequenceNumber'];
        //echo json_encode($ret);
        //error_log($ret);
    } catch (AwsException $e) {
        // output error message if fails
        echo json_encode($e->getMessage());
    }
  }

?>
```

Comment: If `$_POST['sqsObj']` has `{"created":1517517725555,"steamId":"randomsetofnumbers"}` then you should get an object using `$obj = json_decode($_POST['sqsObj']);`.

Comment: json_decode can convert a valid json to php object. are you sure you are passing valid json?

Comment: @TheAlpha Yes, that was my understanding given my research into it. It should work, but it's not. When I log it via `error_log` it shows blank. Again, forgive my ignorance I've never used PHP before.

Comment: @MunimMunna yep, pretty sure. I'm sending an object that I `JSON.stringify` on the JS side. I'll update the question to include that code.

Comment: What you get if you do `var_dump($_POST['sqsObj'])`?

Comment: @TheAlpha it shows blank, perhaps it's how I'm doing it? I couldn't find any other way to debug other than `error_log` which I tried `error_log(var_dump($_POST['sqsObj']))` and it's blank. Is that my issue?

Comment: Which means `$_POST['sqsObj']` is not available. `var_dump($_POST)` and post here.

Comment: @TheAlpha Nope, because when I `error_log($_POST['sqsObj'])` it shows me the data: `{"created":"1517519355437","steamId":"randomsetofnumbers"}`

Comment: @TheAlpha Also, this PHP code is inside of a `if(isset($_POST['sqsObj']) && !empty($_POST['sqsObj']))` statement.

Comment: Just `var_dump($_POST)` and check the result.

Comment: @TheAlpha Do I put the `var_dump` call in a `error_log` function? I tried both with it and without it, shows up as nothing.. maybe it's because I'm using `error_log` ? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do it in the script where your post is being handled.

Comment: It's an ajax call to a PHP script. Regardless, I tried doing a var_dump and I don't see anything. Not sure where it's supposed to print it though... javascript console? terminal? not showing up in either.

Comment: In `sqsController.php` where you are receiving the submission.

Comment: Ok I did the var_dump, like I said it's not showing anything anywhere. Furthermore, when I try to `error_log` the `var_dump` it's just an empty blank line. (doing `var_dump($_POST)`).

Comment: Can you show `sqsController.php`?

Comment: @TheAlpha Np, added it to the question.

Comment: Just make sure that your post request is hitting the correct file by placing `die('something')` at the top of your class.

Comment: Well I know it's hitting the correct file since the logic below that calls Sqs works fine. I did put the `die` function on top, nothing happened though.